# Serialize JTree Object to file

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am trying to serialize a `JTree` object to a file.

This is how I am doing it:

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("serialisation2.txt"));
ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);

// Write objects to file
o.writeObject(jTree1);
                   
o.close();
f.close();
```

Then I am trying to read it with this:

```
FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(new File("serialisation2.txt"));
ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
try{
   while(true){
          jTree2 = new javax.swing.JTree(raíz);

  System.out.println(oi.toString());
          jTree2 = (JTree) oi.readObject();
  }
}
```

But the thing is, it returns `java.io.EOFException` when I do `oi.readObject();`

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like expected behavior. You're reading it indefinitely with `while(true)` so it will throw the exception when it reaches the end of stream. Also why do you create an object with `new` and then immediately assign an object from the stream to the same variable?

Comment: I remove the while and stills throws the exception, I am reading if I can do it another way or something...

Comment: @syzygysyzygy Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also include the full exception message, including the stacktrace, to your question.

Comment: Can't reproduce without the `while` loop.

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* First: Serialize the tree model, not the tree. There is no good case for GUI serializing components.  Second: An object output stream does not serialize as text, so calling it a `.txt` file is incorrect, and will fool the OS into trying to open it in a text editor. Man people would add a `.obj` extension to make it clear it is **not** text. General tips: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  ..

Comment: .. The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 3) I don't know what logic was used to include `while(true){` here, but it is almost certainly wrong. Why did you try to do this repeatedly?

Answer (score 1):

remove while loop, you do not really need `jTree2 = new javax.swing.JTree(raíz);` just jtree2 can get the deserialized value. read more about serialization [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html) and [here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/serializationapi.html)

```
FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(new File("serialisation2.txt"));
ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
jTree2 = (JTree) oi.readObject();
```